# Smartphone accelerometer detects braking on long turns

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, computational-physics, software

We're working on an Android/iOS app that collects phone accelerometer data to detect braking, turning, speeding up etc. The app behavior is mostly what we'd expect, but there's one weird scenario that we cannot understand.

While doing a long turn the data we collect shows braking, but we're absolutely sure the driver does not put her/his feet to the braking pedal and is actually speeding up. We're struggling to understand what could be the reason.

Assuming it's not our app fault (it might turn to be of course), is there an explanation that you could think of?

Edited: First version of the question said "sharp" turns. But it's not happening for quick sharp turns, only for long (nearing 360°), sharp ones.

Comment: What sort of accelerometer response do you define as "braking"?

Comment: @probably_someone The z-axis readings dropping below 0.

Comment: I think that in order to provide an answer to your question you need to provide some data.

Comment: @lidkxx so how is the z-axis defined?

Comment: I would check if the same thing happens if you restrict the degrees of freedom. Put the phone on some spinning device in all possible orientations and check the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we are talking about high lateral acceleration sustained for a significant time, the car may not remain aligned with the direction of motion. That is the velocity vector may not be pointing straight out of the grill.

Gearheads *love* to talk about "oversteer" and "understeer", which mean exactly this kind of dynamic misalignment.<sup>1</sup>

If you are assuming that the direction of "forward" for the vehicle corresponds to the direction of motion you may be making an error. Nor is this a trivial problem to deal with. Correcting for it requires reliably detecting the actual direction of motion.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> After thinking about it for a while and staring at some images on the matter, I believe that if you are measuring an acceleration vector with a 'backward' component relative the frame you are experiencing some understeer.

<sup>2</sup> I believe that the people who instrument racing cars use a small sensor under the frame to measure the direction of relative ground motion, but I'm not sure how it's done.)

Comment: I don't think over/understeer really alter the direction of the car's centreline with respect to the direction of travel: rather they concern the angle of the front wheels with respect to the direction of travel.  A car which oversteers 'wants' to turn into the corner so you need to turn the front wheels less than you expect, while one which understeers wants to not turn, so you need to turn the front wheels more than you expect.  What I think you are taking about is 'drift'.  But my knowledge comes from vintage (<= 1930) cars & books by people who drove them:  terminology may have changed.

Comment: @tfb -- It's still called drifting. There are even drifting competitions nowadays.